# Build Polymorphic Associations Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, polymorphic-associations

So I have following

```
class OptionOfSingleChoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_many  :option_choices, as: :choiceable
end

class OptionChoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :choiceable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end
```

In the new action of the OptionOfSingleChoice controller I am doing following:

```
def new
    @optionofsinglechoice = OptionOfSingleChoice.new()
    setup_three_default_choices()
    3.times {@optionofsinglechoice.option_choices.build}
end
```

and the view for the new action

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= test.fields_for :option_choices do |builder|  %>
        <%= render 'option_choices/form', :f => builder  %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And the form view for the option_choice looks like this

```
<div class="form-group">

  <%= f.text_field(:name, :class => 'form-control') %>
  <%= f.text_field(:price, :class => 'form-control') %>
  <%= f.file_field :choice_image, multiple: false, direct_upload: false,:class => 'form-control' %>

</div>
```

My problem is now that I expect the form for option_choice to render 3 times but its actually just rendered 1 time. I cannot understand why but I suspect that its because the Choisable is not created. When I look at the OptionChoice objects they are looking like this:

```
<OptionChoice id: nil, name: nil, price: nil, choiceable_id: nil, choiceable_type: "OptionOfSingleChoice", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

My guess is that I need to in some way build the :choiceable in some way.
Hopefully you can help me

Comment: Because you build the record 3 times does not mean that you will get three forms rendered in the view. Try something line [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)

Answer (score 0):

Sry brainfart I had forgotten to add
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :option_choices